# Stencil JS: When making request to my API it doesnt go to the server on the box

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, nginx, stenciljs

So im not to sure how to explain this. but basically i have an api route right http://localhost:3000/api/v2/:userID and it works when its both the client and express API are both running on my local machine. But when I deploy it to a linux Ubuntu nginx VPS I can go to to mydomain.com and the client will load fine but it makes request to the users localhost:3000 not the local host of the VPS its on. Oh and if I start the API on my local machine it will access the data and everything fine
I have also tried replacing everywhere in my stencil code that says localhost:3000 with http://vpsIP:3000 and opening the port on the vps which id ideally like to not have to do but either it way it still wont pull the data.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't normally use `localhost` as part of your code - `localhost` to the user's browser is their machine, `localhost` to the server is the server machine. If the application domain is `mydomain.com`, and the API is located anywhere else, then you have to include the API domain `vpsIP:3000` in the request url, or you have to redirect that request from `mydomain.com` to `vpsIP:3000` - which can be done using a proxy, or in the web server layer, or even in the application controller.

Comment: Ye I fixed this by doing a proxy passthrough with Nginx then change all API routes in my front-end code to mydomain.com/api/